# Sending 0x00 using I2C

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c

I am using the Wire class to have two Arduino Unos communicate using I2C.  It seems that the Wire class ends transmission on a value of 0.  So if I send bytes 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, and 0x04, the master receives: 0x01, 0x02, 0xFF, 0xFF.

It seems odd that a communication network designed for processor communication cannot send a 0x00.  All the examples for I2C that I have seen use ASCII only.  Inter-processor communication restricted to ASCII does not seem to make any sense.  Am I missing something with I2C or is this just an implementation limitation of the Arduino Wire class?

Master

```
void loop() {
  Wire.requestFrom(2, 4); 

  while(Wire.available()) { 
    byte b = (byte) Wire.read(); 
    Serial.println(b); 
  }

  delay(1000);
}
```

Slave

```
void requestEvent() {
  char bytes[4] = {0x01,0x02,0x00,0x04};
  Wire.write(bytes);
}
```

The results are: 1 2 255 255.

When that 0x00 was 0x03 I got the expected: 1 2 3 4.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using for your transmission, both for TX and RX?

Comment: I2C is capable of transmitting arbitrary bytes on the bus, as long as the address byte and stop/stop sequences are correctly generated. Can you post the code for both Arduinos?

Comment: I²C can absolutely transmit 0x00.  If you can't, it's an implementation issue, not a protocol flaw.

Comment: Take a look at my question and answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028764/is-there-a-general-i2c-command-to-see-if-a-device-is-still-present-on-the-bus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing an array of `char`s to `Wire.write()`... This makes `Wire` treat the argument as a null-terminated string, and therefore the `NULL` byte terminates the transmission.  If you want to send `byte`s, call the `write()` function once for each byte, passing it `byte` types.

Alternatively, you can call the `write(const uint8_t *, size_t);` version: you pass it a pointer to / array of bytes, but you also have to give it a size of your data array.

Comment: @jedwards: if you pass the size then yes. But without it, there is no version of `write()` that takes an array of numbers... and besides, how would it know the size of the array? Unless you want it to treat `bytes[4]` as a `long`, but I think that's inadvisable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Wire.begin() and Wire.beginTransmission() (with correct address) happening before calling Wire.write()?